# mysql errors abound after installing Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework 1.0.0

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

In trying to adapt my membership class on my current website to use the Identity model, after installing the package through nuget, I get the following error, which I assume will surface for every model in my website.

App_Code.RangeProjectionsModel.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'.

I ALREADY HAVE mySql installed (connector 6.8.1). The nuget upgraded me to entity framework 6.0.2 from 5.0.0. Im assuming this is where the error lies but I didn't find much by googling.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the mysql forums

Add this line under `<entityFramework>` in your webconfig file

```
 <providers> <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
 type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices,
 MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider> </providers>
```

You must be using connector 6.8.1 or higher.

Add a reference to MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 to your project.
It's generally in this folder
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.1\Assemblies\v4.5

It should work fine once these changes are implemented

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried so already look into using the nuget command line tool to install your package. It gives you more control specifying what version of a package you want to download.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console

Comment: I used the package manager to install it. I found the solution and posted it.